# How does the flow of object creation work in Java?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

New to Java and OOP in general here.

I'm trying to understand when an object's members are able to be used. Specifically, why can't I pass an instance variable to a constructor when calling it within the class? Example code below:

```
public class Point {

    public String name;

    {
        name = "Henry";
    }

    public Point()
    {
        this(this.name); // cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
    }

    public Point(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Something like this has been asked before, but I didn't know how to ask Google what I'm explaining here. I know I can't reference `this.name` within the `this(this.name)` call because an object reference hasn't been created yet, but how exactly is Java calling the constructor?

The only time that constructor is going to be executed is when an object is created using `new Point()`, by which time an object reference *will* be available, and the compiler wouldn't have anything to complain about. If it was possible to assign `this.name` to a variable, and then pass that to `this(variable)`, it would work would it not? What is the huge difference? I'm completely misunderstanding something here.

This is how I'm visualizing it, which is clearly not correct:

`Point myPoint = new Point();`

`myPoint.name` now equals `"Henry"`

within the `Point()` constructor, execute `this(this.name) // which should be "Henry"`

Comment: The boring details should be mostly in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html (in your case, what would happen if the super class had declared that field and would want to set it in it's constructor? That's roughly why super must run before you can use anything)

Comment: When you do `new Point()`, then that's like `new` being a method that returns a reference to a `Point` object that just got constructed on the heap (under the hood just a bit of memory that holds all instance variables/references/... https://dzone.com/articles/java-object-memory ). It's not going to create an `Object` first. It's directly a `Point`. But a `Point` is a `Object` (through inheritance) so the `Object` constructor will find what it knows to expect. You can therefore not take away when you `extend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only time that constructor is going to be executed is when an object is created using new Point(), **by which time an object reference will be available**, and the compiler wouldn't have anything to complain about.

I'd say that the key point here is that the object reference is only available *after* the constructor has been called. Hence referencing this *during* the constructor's operation doesn't really make sense.

Also remember that with inheritance, you can have multiple constructors being called before a particular object is instantiated/created. For example:

```
public class ParentPoint {
    public String name = "Parent Point";

    public ParentPoint() {
        // do something
    }
}

public class Point extends ParentPoint {

    public Point() {
        super();
        // do something else
    }

}
```

In this case you'll have two constructors that are called before Point is fully instantiated (so the flow you mention in your OP isn't always that straightforward).

Xavier Silva's answer code is a good one, and also having getters and setters would be ideal too:

```
public class Point {

    public String name = "Henry";

    public Point() {

    }

    public Point(String name) {
        this.name = name; //changes current value (Henry) to the one sent as an argument.
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point pointA = new Point();
        Point pointB = new Point("Other name");

        System.out.println(pointA.name); // Henry
        System.out.println(pointB.name); // Other name

        pointA.setName("New name");
        System.out.println(pointA.getName()); // New name
    }
}
```

The final bit demonstrates getters and setters, the rest of the code is unmodified.

Comment: Thank you, I read some more and understand that the object is initialized only after the constructor is executed. I couldn't refer to `this.name` within `this()` because doing so would be trying to manipulate the reference before executing the superclass constructor. I also found out that a constructor can chain to only one other constructor. So `this(this.name)` was used in place of `super()` expecting `Point(String name)` (which was what `this()` was pointing to) to execute it, but was instead told to handle `this.name` before any constructor had executed `super()`. Do I have it right?

Comment: Apologies for the delay - I'm a little unsure about some aspects of your comment but yes, what you say does seem to be correct overall.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers completely to your question because it is a little confusing, but I will give my best:

In order to create a new object you use the `new` operand, like `Point point = new Point();`. 
Your objects can/should contain attributes and you started it right when creating `public String name;` (although you should search about this because they should not be public). If you have to assign a default value to an attribute, you have to do it right after its declaration (e.g. `public String name = "Henry";`. Once again, you may want to search about java constants to solve this problem.

This code may help you understand what (I think) you want to do:

```
public class Point {

    public String name = "Henry";

    public Point() {

    }

    public Point(String name) {
        this.name = name; //changes current value (Henry) to the one sent as an argument.
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point pointA = new Point();
        Point pointB = new Point("Other name");

        System.out.println(pointA.name);
        System.out.println(pointB.name);
    }
}
```

In this code you can find an instantiation of an empty object (`new Point();`) and one with the name "Other name" (`new Point("Other name");`).

If you run it, you can see the differences between both instantiations.

Hope this helps you!

**Edit:**
P.S. You may also want to search about getters/setters.

Comment: This is a great answer but if you want to take the long route you can simply find the documentation on this matter for a more detailed view on it.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish your goal by emptying the this(this.name) constructor - that way, calling an empty constructor - new Point() - leaves name as Henry, and using the other constructor - e.g. new Point("Bob") - would set that name ("Bob") as name.

I believe you could also do it by replacing first "this" with "super".